# Finding number of cases , arranging people around circular table

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a circular table and it contains 10 seats how many way we can arrange 15 people in this table ?

Please Correct me:

$ \dbinom {15}{10} \cdot \dfrac {15!}{5!} $

Comment: Are the seats distinct?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure

Comment: Do you consider two  arrangements as equal if one arrangement is generated by rotation or reflection from the other arangement?

Comment: The *convention* for circular tables is that arrangements that differ by a rotation are counted as being the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rather depends on what you regard as identical seating arrangements.

Start with ${15 \choose 10}$ for choosing ten out of fifteen, as you presumably did.

Multiply by $10!$ for the ways of seating these ten in identified seats.

Perhaps divide by $10$ if each of the rotations count as the same.

Comment: if those seats are not identical,what would the answer be ?

Comment: If the rotations do not count as the same then do not divide by $10$.  But see André Nicolas's comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from $n$ objects *with order mattering* is given by

$$_n P_k = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = k! \left({n \atop k}\right)$$

(read "n *permute* k"). Explanation: Take $n$ objects. Choose one for the first position, leaving $n-1$ left. Then choose from those $n-1$ for the second. And so on, making $k$ choices in all. Note that the precise nature of the choices does not affect the *number* of ways of making the choices, and so by the multiplication principle, you have the given product.

So in your case, you want to choose 10 from 15 *with order mattering*, thus you have $_{15} P_{10}$. If rotations are not to be distinguished, then divide this by 10 to get $\frac{_{15} P_{10}}{10} = 9! \left({15 \atop 10}\right)$, which is 1,089,728,640.